# All my links in my react js projects have become unclickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react` v17 and `react-router-dom` v6 in my project and my `Route` component use `element` instead of `component`. My problem begin when I try to get and show data belong the server and I use `useffect` hook.

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeFour />} />
  <Route path="/articles/:page" element={<Article />} exact />
<Routes>
```

Example of link

```html
<a
  className="nav-link active"
  id="pills-home-tab"
  data-bs-toggle="pill"
  href="#pills-home"
  role="tab"
  aria-controls="pills-home" 
  aria-selected="true"
>
  Most Popular
</a>
```

I would like to see my links clickable.

Comment: I don’t see any links.

Comment: Additional information should go into the question. It’s not clear how this helps, though, or what kind of diagnosis is expected with the information provided.

Comment: What do you mean by not-clickable? That the navigation doesn't work or that the link don't receive the click event?

Comment: link don't receive the click event and when i put cursor hover link the cursor appearance don't change

Comment: What click event are you expecting to see/handle? I don't see any element with any attached `onClick` handler. I'm guessing you are trying to use hash links *somewhere* in your app and because you aren't using the `Link` or `NavLink` component `react-router-dom` knows nothing of the navigation action and the app isn't navigating/rendering what you expect. I doubt there's any issue with link interactiveness or click events. Can you [edit] to more clearly explain what the problem is that you are trying to solve for and provide a more complete [mcve]?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like the issue might be related to the href attribute in your anchor () tags. In React Router v6, the href attribute is not used for navigation within the application. Instead, you should use the to attribute provided by the Link component from react-router-dom.

To fix the issue, you can replace your anchor tags with the Link component. Here's an example:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

<Link
  className="nav-link active"
  id="pills-home-tab"
  to="#pills-home"
  role="tab"
  aria-controls="pills-home" 
  aria-selected="true"
>
  Most Popular
</Link>
```

Make sure you have the Link component imported from react-router-dom, and then replace your anchor tags () with the Link component. By doing this, your links should be clickable and properly handle navigation within your React application.

Additionally, if you have a specific route defined for "/#pills-home", make sure to include it in your Routes component to ensure that the corresponding component is rendered when the link is clicked.

Comment: In `react-router` the `href` attribute ***is used*** on the actual anchor tag from the `Link` component that is rendered into the DOM. That said, your point is a bit irrelevant since OP isn't even using a `Link` component, so their raw anchor tag with `href` attribute is correct syntactically. `react-router` also doesn't use the URL hash for route paths. The "path" `"/#pills-home"` would be matched to a route rendering on `path="/"`. The hash, similar to the queryString, is not considered when path matching.